# XAMPP Apache Start Error

Tags: apache, error-handling, xampp, port

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsT3o.png)

This is the problem that I currently have. I tried some options like running it as administrator, changing the port on http.conf & httpd-ssl.conf but it doesn't work. I hope you can help...

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302430/xampp-apache-config-test-fail-error-symbol-not-found-on-modperl/72664641#72664641

Answer (score 0):

- check if your apache is not already running,
- run apachectl configtest (or change apachectl to your apache runtime),
- check if default config is working,
- check if config with modified dirs is working,
- check your apache server logs (Im sure you'll find clue in there)

btw. from the error message it looks like something (tomcat server) is already running on 8080 port so you'll either need to change port of tomcat or change the port on which apache is trying to start (/etc/httpd/httpd.conf + virtuals dir or /etc/apache2/*.conf) - it looks like it wants to start on 8080 which is quite default port for web server (apart of 80 which is added by default so when you're writing something.com your browser is really going to something.com:80 - just you dont see it)